# Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

Tags: c++, qt, exception, char

I created a simple steganography library and I'm trying to create a small Qt 5.0.2 app to test it out. It consists of two textEdits that are used to store & display the path names, and two buttons that pop-up a file dialog to choose the files, txt and bmp, to allow the former to be "embedded" into the latter.

But when I click the "generate" button, it throws up "Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'.

```c++
void MainWindow::on_generate_clicked()
{
    BmpFile bm(MainWindow::bmpName);
    char *outputFile = "test1.bmp";

    if( bm.hide(MainWindow::bmpName, MainWindow::txtName, outputFile) == 0 )
    {
        printf("Hidding done.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error!");
    }
}
```

is the Qt slot that throws the error.

```c++
void MainWindow::on_selFile_clicked()
{
    QString txtname(MainWindow::txtName);
    txtname = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open file"),"",tr("Files (*.txt)"));
    ui->fileBox->setText(txtname);
    QByteArray ba = txtname.toLocal8Bit();
    MainWindow::txtName = ba.data();
}

void MainWindow::on_selBitmap_clicked()
{
    QString bmpname=(MainWindow::bmpName);
    bmpname = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open file"),"",tr("Files (*.bmp)"));
    ui->bmpBox->setText(bmpname);
    QByteArray ba = bmpname.toLocal8Bit();
    MainWindow::bmpName = ba.data();
}
```

are the two slots that handle and store the two files

And [this](http://pastebin.com/wiaT1Ytc) is the library.

I have a feeling it's something to do with converting to a QString and back, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Could you be more specific? What are you calling when the error occurs? What is the specific error text? How do the second two slots factor into the problem? Please edit the question to provide these specifics.

Comment: @CoryKlein I've edited to reflect the changes.

Comment: I expect its throwing "("File doesn't exits or wrong Filename.\n");" from your external library.

Comment: @drescherjm I've tried with multiple files and non-existing files, and that error message only throws in those cases.

Comment: Why don't you keep the filename as a QString?

Comment: This most likely is your problem code: QByteArray ba = bmpname.toLocal8Bit();
    MainWindow::bmpName = ba.data();

Comment: I really hope  MainWindow::bmpName is not a char* since that can't possibly work because the  QByteArray is on the stack and will be invalid after either of the slots exit.

Comment: Also can't you use the builtin support for bitmaps in Qt instead of the external code.

Comment: I tried having it as a QString, but that meant re-writing the entire library to use QFile::Read/Write instead of the C functions I'm more used to. That was the only real way I could convert a char* to a QString, and yes it is. What would you recommend instead then?

I wasn't aware it had native support.

Comment: It does not mean rewriting the library. It means you convert from QString to const char* when you construct bm.

Comment: Qt doesn't use exceptions at all, so exceptions comes form your library. Since Qt doesn't use exceptions it doesn't catch any that is why it ends with a crash. Apparently you didn't write good test for your library and you are throwing crapy object.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion on the OP, I recommend that you keep the file name as a QString. Replace char* bmpName; with QString strBmpName; in your header. Then convert the QString to a char* for the following line.

```
BmpFile bm(MainWindow::bmpName);
```

to

```
QByteArray ba = strBmpName.toLocal8Bit();
BmpFile bm(ba.data());
```

Comment: `const_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`, probably.

Comment: I'll have a forage and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: You must never use `toLocal8Bit().data()`! `data()` returns a buffer that will alive as long as its owner (the QByteArray) is alive. And QByteArray is temporary and will be destroyed immediately after `data()` call. So, the buffer could be invalid at the moment you're trying to use it. I actually experienced this effect sometimes (it depends on compiler and optimization flags, of course).

Comment: I see. http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa

Comment: I removed the part about needing a const_cast since that is not necessary in this case. From here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#data